# How can I access choices of the model in the serializers and obtain a json view

Tags: python, django

models.py

```
MSI_OPTIONS = (
    (ANC1, 'AN1'),
    (ANC2, 'AN2'),
    (ANC3, 'AN3'),
    (ANC4, 'AN4'),
    (DELIVERY, 'Delivery'),
    (FAMILY_PLANNING, 'Family Planning'),
)

class MSIService(models.Model):
    girl = models.ForeignKey(Girl, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    option = models.CharField(choices=MSI_OPTIONS, default=ANC1, max_length=250)
```

I a'm trying to obtain a JSON object counting how many time each `MSI_OPTIONS` is used like

> { "ANC1":3, "ANC2":4 "ANC3":4 "ANC4":10 }

Note: each girl has one of `MSI_OPTIONS`.

Answer (score 0):

What you might be looking for is [django-aggregations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet)

And maybe something like:

```py
aggregated_result = MSIService.objects.annotate(num_options=Count('option'))
aggregated_result_dict = {
    element.girl, element.num_options for element in aggregated_result
}
print(aggregated_result_dict)
```